# Including pages based on URL in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is this a terrible way to include pages based on the URL? (using `mod_rewrite` through `index.php`)

```
if($url === '/index.php/'.$user['username']) {
    include('app/user/page.inc.php');
}

// Upload *
else if($url === '/index.php/'.$user['username'].'/Upload') {
    include('app/user/upload.inc.php');
}

// Another page *
else if($url === '/index.php/AnotherPage') {
    include('page/another_page.inc.php');
}
```

I'm using `$_GET['variables']` through `mod_rewrite` for

```
^(.+)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

and a couple other base pages.  But, those are just for the first argument on base files.  The above if / else examples are also case sensitive which is really not good.

What are your thoughts on this?

How would I `mod_rewrite` these 2nd / 3rd etc. argument off of the `index.php`?

Would that be totally SEO incompatible with the aforementioned example?

Comment: This includes the file inside the scope of the function running this code. Is that what you want? See Example 2 in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, per se.
What do you mean by "these 2nd / 3rd etc. argument"?

You can do the same steps in a more readable/maintainable manner as follows:

```
$urls = array(
 '/index.php/'.$user['username']           => 'app/user/page.inc.php',
 '/index.php/'.$user['username'].'/Upload' => 'app/user/upload.inc.php',
 '/index.php/AnotherPage'                  => 'page/another_page.inc.php'
);
$url = $urls[$url];
```

If the '.inc.php' is consistant, you can remove that from each item of the array and add it at the end:
`$url = $urls[$url].'inc.php'`

Along the same lines, you can write the array in reverse (switch the keys and values in above array) and use preg_grep to search it. This will allow you to search the url without being case sensitive, as well as allowing wildcards.

```
$url = key( preg_grep("/$url/i", $urls));
```

See [Here](http://codepad.org/vyyPiWuR) for a live interactive example.

Note that this is far less efficient, though for wildcard matches it is the best way.
(And for most pages, the inefficiency is livable.)